# Парсер не переходит на другую страницу

Tags: java, парсер

Пишу парсер, учусь, вот код:

```
public class TP {

public static Document getPage() throws MalformedURLException, IOException {

String url = "https://steamcommunity.com/market/";


Document page = (Jsoup.parse(new URL(url), 3000));
 return page;

}



public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
    TM();

}


public static void TM() throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
    Document page = getPage();

    for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
        page = Jsoup.connect("https://steamcommunity.com/market/search?appid=570#p"+i+"_popular_desc").get();

        Element allPage = page.selectFirst("div[id=mainContents]");
        Elements weap = allPage.select("a[class=market_listing_row_link]");

        for (Element data : weap) {
                String name = data.select("span[class=market_listing_item_name]").text();
                String quantity = data.select("div[class=market_listing_right_cell market_listing_num_listings]").text();
                String price = data.select("span[class=market_table_value normal_price]").text();

                System.out.println(name + "    " + quantity + "   " + price );

          }

       }
    }

  }
```

Использовал этот же способ для перехода по страницам с другим сайтом - все работало, с этим почему-то просто несколько раз повторяются данные с одной страницы (в данном случае 3 раза), а не парсится последовательно 3 страницы, как должно быть

Answer (score 0):

```
https://steamcommunity.com/market/search?appid=570#p0_popular_desc
```

возвращает пустую страницу, отсчёт необходимо выполнять с `i = 1`

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
```

Comment: почему-то не работает, так же ро кругу 3 раза выдает страницу первую